# AutoSize for Label / TextBox in .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I'm quite simply going totally bonkers with the omission of the AutoSize-property for the Label and TextBox controls in .NET Compact Framework. I have a simple app, that's supposed to list a bunch of text data (generally between one-liners to a few paragraphs of text) in a TabControl. Everything else works smoothly, but my attempts at dynamically resizing the Label / TextBox -controls I use to display the text are failing miserably.

Here's the way I've tried doing it:

```
/*
Variables: 
s = The text intended for the TextBox
NewTB = TextBox object
width = Intended width
whiteSpaceAdjustment = amount of pixels per line to adjust "wasted" whitespace due to wrapping
*/

String[] linesArray = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n").Split(new char[] { '\n' });

int lines = 0;

int lineHeight = g.MeasureString(
        s.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""),
        LabelFont
    ).ToSize().Height;

foreach (String str in linesArray) {
    if (str.Length == 0) {
        lines++;
        continue;
    }
    szz = g.MeasureString(str, LabelFont).ToSize();
    lines += szz.Width / (width - whiteSpaceAdjustment);
    lines += (szz.Width % width) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
NewTB.Height = lines * lineHeight;
NewTB.Width = width;
```

...but the problem is that the range needed for whiteSpaceAdjustment is too huge. When it's large enough to actually work on the most extreme cases (paragraphs made mostly up of really long words), most boxes end up being a line or two too tall.

I'm probably going to have to implement word wrapping myself, but before I go there, is there anybody with a nice clean solution ready for this?

I'd be forever grateful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this article

[www.mobilepractices.com/2007/12/multi-line-graphicsmeasurestring.html](http://www.mobilepractices.com/2007/12/multi-line-graphicsmeasurestring.html)

Make sure you also look at the link at the bottom of the article to be able to use different fonts.

If you are using .Net CF 3.5 you may be able to turn their example into an extension method. Otherwise I'd suggest that you create a new control inheriting from the framework control.

Comment: No worries, I had the same problem myself.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I developed for auto re-size width of label in WinCE.

```
/// <summary>
/// This class provides dynamic size labels, i.e. as the text grows lable width will grow with it. 
/// </summary>
public partial class AutoSizeLabel : UserControl
{
    private string _strText;
    private const int padding = 10;

    public AutoSizeLabel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _strText;
        }
        set
        {
            _strText = value;
            Refresh();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        SizeF size = pe.Graphics.MeasureString(this.Text, this.Font);
        this.Size = new Size((int)size.Width + padding, this.Height);

        if (this.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            pe.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text,
                this.Font,
                new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor),
                (this.ClientSize.Width - size.Width) / 2,
                (this.ClientSize.Height - size.Height) / 2);
        }
        // Calling the base class OnPaint
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great for width, thank you for sharing. Any clues on auto-sizing height? I have to explicitly set it because without it the label is 150 heigh instead of 20.

Comment: I discovered width is correct when accessing from this.Controls[i].Width just FYI.

Comment: @Zacho: You want label with fix width and dynamic height?

Comment: No I want it totally dynamic. But when I used this code as is the height was 150 by default. Strange...

Comment: @Zacho: I am not a expert in winCE programing (sorry about that) but i think you should have one field fix ether width or height so that other one can be dynamic. In given code height is fix and resizing is done on width.